# Fast grep multiple values from a compressed file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

Are there any better method than the following command?

```
zgrep ABC test.tgz | grep DEF | grep GHI | ..
```

By better I mean performance and ease of use (i.e. type the command from memory)

Comment: You can also use the grep -e option to specify multiple patterns.

Comment: @mbratch that will grep for ABC or DEF or GHI. Question appears to indicate he wants to grep for ABC then grep those results for DEF then grep those results for GHI.

Comment: @MattGreen yep I just had a brain fart

Answer (score 1):

I seems to that you do an and in any order.

```
cat file
ABC
ABC DEF
ABC DEF GHI
ABC GHI DEF
DEF
```

```
zgrep ABC file | grep DEF | grep GHI
ABC DEF GHI
ABC GHI DEF
```

This can be done like this

```
awk '/ABC/ && /DEF/ && /GHI/' file # here patter can be in any order
ABC DEF GHI
ABC GHI DEF
```

```
awk '/ABC.*DEF.*GHI/' file  # here patterns need to be in that order.
or
grep "ABC.*DEF.*GHI" file
ABC DEF GHI
```

`grep` is not good to do and in any order.

Comment: +1 1st awk is the way to go, I was going to post same then saw your answer and abandoned mine.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head I would say no. You are grepping for results from within the results of a previous grep so the pipes are the best way to do this without additional code which would lower the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed one liner to do the same, should be faster than multiple `grep`:

```
sed -n -e '/ABC/{/DEF/{/GHI/p;};}' file
```